# How to do one-off import or data migration?

Tags: import, migration

Is there a built-in workflow or process for running one-time wordpress database updates relating to things like taxonomy, new categories, filters, hooks, plugin setup, etc?

Right now I'm putting all of these programmatic database updates into my custom functions.php file. This feels wrong since the code will run repeatedly even though it's for a one-time task. Deploying then redeploying with the changes commented out also feels cloogy. I'm coming from other technology stacks where there is a built-in workflow for managing one-time database migrations and imports. Is there something like this for Wordpress?

Comment: Is this for a plugin or theme?

Comment: No - I mean the question for the general case.  I have a custom taxonomy, custom categories, custom post type, not specific to a plugin or theme. Right now, I'm making changes  in advance of a csv import, but I want to understand the normal workflow for future taxonomy updates, etc. that I want to perform programmatically.

Comment: I thought perhaps one-time migrations of any sort could follow  same workflow, plugin or not. (Am using a child theme for theme specific code, separately.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would suggest - store your theme version in the database, compare it with your package version, if there's a difference then load in your upgrade/install operations:

```
define( 'THEME_PREFIX_VERSION', 'X.X' );

/**
 * Run upgrade/install.
 */
function theme_prefix_install() {
    require_once dirname( __file__ ) . '/install.php';
}

if ( version_compare( get_option( 'theme_prefix_version' ), THEME_PREFIX_VERSION, '<' ) )
    add_action( 'init', 'theme_prefix_install' );
```

Then in `install.php`:

```
if ( ! defined( 'THEME_PREFIX_VERSION' ) )
    exit;

$version = get_option( 'theme_prefix_version' );

if ( version_compare( $version, '1.0', '<' ) ) {
    // Upgrade code required for version 1.0
}


if ( version_compare( $version, '1.1', '<' ) ) {
    // Upgrade code required for version 1.1
}

// And so forth

// All updated, store current package version
update_option( 'theme_prefix_version', THEME_PREFIX_VERSION );
```

Comment: so if i'm asking unrelated to a theme, you're saying to put it in a theme?

Comment: Doesn't matter, plugin/theme, whichever suits the project.

Comment: So my customizations (unrelated to an external theme or plugin) should be bundled as one of these so it can then be versioned? Sorry wordpress ideology newbie.

Comment: Change of plan, see new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a worker plugin for the sole intent of running an upgrade. The code runs on activation, and then can simply be deactivated again, without affecting runtime/performance:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Project Name Upgrader
 * Description: Activate to run one-time upgrades.
 * Version:     0.1
 * Author:      Author
 */

function project_name_upgrade() {
    // All your upgrade code
}

register_activation_hook( __file__, 'project_name_upgrade' );
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Apparently immediately after activation, the page redirects before any of my embedded actions get called (to create custom post type, add taxonomy, etc). Looks like these lines need to run recurringly (in init) rather than one time as well, which I find strange since I thought they just got stored in the database. I do like your idea of segregating by plugin.

Comment: Process flow section describes the timing problem: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook